# Export table values Meteor Blaze

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, multidimensional-array, meteor-blaze

I am running into some difficulty exporting a table to csv in meteor/blaze. I am following: [http://rafaelquintanilha.com/export-your-json-data-to-csv-format/][1].

I have a Template.event that is triggering the export button

```
Template.export.onCreated( () => {
  Template.instance().subscribe('table');
});
Template.export.helpers({
  exportContacts() {
    return Contacts.find();
  }
});
Template.export.events({
  'click .export-data' () {
    MyAppExporter.exportAllContacts();
  }
});
```

it is calling exportAllContacts() in a global helper

```
 MyAppExporter = {
    exportAllContacts: function() {
        var self = this;
        Meteor.call("exportContacts", function(error, data) {
            if ( error ) {
                alert(error);
                return false;
            }
            var csv = Papa.unparse(data);
            self._downloadCSV(csv);
        });
    },
    _downloadCSV: function(csv) {
        var blob = new Blob([csv]);
        var a = window.document.createElement("a");
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob, {type: "text/plain"});
        a.download = "contacts.csv";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    }
}
```

and the helper is calling a Meteor.method exportContacts

```
  Meteor.methods({
    exportContacts: function() {
        let fields = [
            "Email",
            “Some Contact",
            "Created Date",
            "Hard Bounce",
            "Unsubscribed"
        ];
        let data = [];
        let contacts = Contacts.find().fetch();
    for(let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
      let contact = contacts[i];
      let contactString = JSON.stringify(contact);
        _.each(contactString, function(c) {
        console.log("Inside Loop", contactString);
            data.push([
                c.contact.emailAddress,
                c.contact.someContact,
                c.contact.creationDate,
                c.contact.hardBounceBack,
                c.contact.unsubscribed
            ]);
        console.log("DATA", data)
        return {fields: fields, data: data};
        });
    }
  }
});
```

I keep getting an error that “emailAddress is not defined exportContacts.js:20:17

```
20160426-22:00:47.957(-4)? Inside Loop {"_id":"dRnXRdZrbR9CYdmBx","contact":[{"emailAddress":"fred@weasly.com","someContact":"No","creationDate":"N/A","hardBounceBack":"N/A","unsubscribed":"N/A"}]}

I20160426-22:00:48.029(-4)? Exception while invoking method 'exportContacts' ReferenceError: emailAddress is not defined
I20160426-22:00:48.029(-4)?     at server/methods/exportContacts.js:20:17
I20160426-22:00:48.029(-4)?     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore.js:142:22)
I20160426-22:00:48.029(-4)?     at _loop (server/methods/exportContacts.js:17:7)
```

but I cannot seem to figure out how to access the contacts. I am logging it out (see above in logs). Any help would be appreciated.

ADDED LOGS
let contacts = Contacts.find().fetch(); console.log(contacts)

```
I20160427-09:06:23.484(-4)? CONTACTS [ { _id: 'dRnXRdZrbR9CYdmBx', contact: [ [Object] ] },
I20160427-09:06:23.484(-4)?   { _id: 'LHmW4R9PLM5D7cZxr', contact: [ [Object] ] },
I20160427-09:06:23.484(-4)?   { _id: 'jBdqQXz2b8itXJowX', contact: [ [Object] ] },
I20160427-09:06:23.484(-4)?   { _id: 'bnDvNGX3i879z4wr2', contact: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

c.contact[0].emailAddress logged out

```
I20160427-09:22:08.142(-4)? Inside Loop {"_id":"dRnXRdZrbR9CYdmBx","contact":[{"emailAddress":"fred@weasly.com","someContact":"No","creationDate":"N/A","hardBounceBack":"N/A","unsubscribed":"N/A"}]}
I20160427-09:22:08.217(-4)? Exception while invoking method 'exportContacts' TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
I20160427-09:22:08.217(-4)?     at server/methods/exportContacts.js:21:7
I20160427-09:22:08.217(-4)?     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore.js:142:22)
I20160427-09:22:08.217(-4)?     at _loop (server/methods/exportContacts.js:18:7)
I20160427-09:22:08.218(-4)?     at [object Object].exportContacts (server/methods/exportContacts.js:15:46)
```

Comment: Can you use the [edit] link on your question to include some sample documents from the result you get with `let contacts = Contacts.find().fetch(); console.log(contacts)`? From mere inspection, `c.contact` is an array and you are trying to access a property from an array hence the error. Can you try as well `c.contact[0].emailAddress`?

Comment: I added the logs for you chridam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the _.each loop you are accessing the wrong data items. You can also use a _.each loop instead of the outer for loop too. If you do :

```
let contacts = Contacts.find().fetch();
_.each(contacts, function(contact) {
  _each(contact.contact, function(c) {
      data.push(
          {
              "email": c.emailAddress,
              "contact": c. someContact,
              "creationDate" : c.creationDate,
              "bounceBack": c.hardBounceBack,
              "unsubscribed": c.unsubscribed
          }            
  })
})
```

This should solve your problem. This way you are looping through the outer contacts that is coming back from the fetch and then looping through the contact array from each element. This should be the most direct way to get down to the data you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line: `_.each(contactString, function(c) {`

It should read: `_.each(contact, function(c) {`

:)